# I can't use Queue in my abstract data type

Tags: c++, queue

I am working on Graphs and I created a Graph class and added `#include <queue>` to my code. If I write `queue<int> MyQueue` in main function it works well. But if I write the same code `queue<int> MyQueue` in my class Graph it gives me a runtime error. Waiting for your help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

class AdjListImp_Graph
{
    public: 
    vector<int> *array[8];
    vector<int> List[8];
    AdjListImp_Graph(){
        for(int i=1; i<8; i++)
            array[i] = &List[i];
    }
};

class AdjMatrixImp_Graph
{
    public:
    int AdjMatrix[7][7];
    queue<int> MyList; // !Having problem with this code!
    AdjMatrixImp_Graph(){
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
                AdjMatrix[i][j] = 0;
    }
};

int main (void)
{
    AdjListImp_Graph MyGraph_3a, MyGraph_3b, MyGraph_3c;
    MyGraph_3a.List[1].push_back(4);
    MyGraph_3a.List[2].push_back(4);
    MyGraph_3a.List[4].push_back(7);
    MyGraph_3a.List[6].push_back(3);
    MyGraph_3a.List[7].push_back(5);
    MyGraph_3b.List[1].push_back(2);
    MyGraph_3b.List[2].push_back(5);    MyGraph_3b.List[2].push_back(7);
    MyGraph_3b.List[4].push_back(3);    MyGraph_3b.List[4].push_back(6);
    MyGraph_3b.List[5].push_back(4);
    MyGraph_3b.List[6].push_back(1);    MyGraph_3b.List[6].push_back(7);
    MyGraph_3c.List[2].push_back(1);
    MyGraph_3c.List[3].push_back(4);    MyGraph_3c.List[3].push_back(6);
    MyGraph_3c.List[4].push_back(5);
    MyGraph_3c.List[5].push_back(2);
    MyGraph_3c.List[6].push_back(7);
    MyGraph_3c.List[7].push_back(2);
    /********************************************************************************************************/
    AdjMatrixImp_Graph My_Graph_3a, My_Graph_3b, My_Graph_3c;
    My_Graph_3a.AdjMatrix[1][4] = 1;
    My_Graph_3a.AdjMatrix[2][4] = 1;
    My_Graph_3a.AdjMatrix[3][2] = 1;
    My_Graph_3a.AdjMatrix[4][7] = 1; // 4'ten 7'ye yol   var.
    My_Graph_3a.AdjMatrix[6][3] = 1;
    My_Graph_3a.AdjMatrix[7][5] = 1;
    My_Graph_3b.AdjMatrix[1][2] = 1;
    My_Graph_3b.AdjMatrix[2][5] = 1;    My_Graph_3b.AdjMatrix[2][7] = 1;
    My_Graph_3b.AdjMatrix[4][3] = 1;    My_Graph_3b.AdjMatrix[4][6] = 1;
    My_Graph_3b.AdjMatrix[5][4] = 1;
    My_Graph_3b.AdjMatrix[6][1] = 1;    My_Graph_3b.AdjMatrix[6][7] = 1;
    My_Graph_3c.AdjMatrix[2][1] = 1;
    My_Graph_3c.AdjMatrix[3][4] = 1;    My_Graph_3c.AdjMatrix[3][6] = 1;
    My_Graph_3c.AdjMatrix[4][5] = 1;
    My_Graph_3c.AdjMatrix[5][2] = 1;
    My_Graph_3c.AdjMatrix[6][7] = 1;
    My_Graph_3c.AdjMatrix[7][2] = 1;

    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to post the exact error message and a code snippet. We can't help you without that information.

Comment: Hmm. Not really given us much to go on. What is the runtime error? Do you have a "#include <queue> statement in your class header?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zuBg7Qhk
Here is my code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your initialization of `AdjMatrixImp_Graph::AdjMatrix` in the constructor of `AdjMatrixImp_Graph`, you are going beyond the array boundary. It possibly writes into the memory area of `AdjMatrixImp_Graph::MyList`, and corrupts its structure.

<s>Change the loops to `for (int i;i<7;i++) for(int j;j<7;j++){...`.</s> Or you can use `memset(AdjMatrix, 0, sizeof(AdjMatrix));`

Checking the `main` code suggests that the definition of `AdjMatrix` should be changed to `AdjMatrix[8][8]`.

Comment: Thank you. Now I fixed the runtime error. But unfortunately I still cant use queue in my adt

Comment: @KutluhanMetin What do you mean by `can't use queue in my adt`?

Comment: I want to use queue in My Class Graph. I can still use it in main and can't use it in my class.

Comment: @KutluhanMetin After changing to `int AdjMatrix[8][8];`, the program you posted compiles and runs with no error.

Answer (score 1):

Change the declaration

```
    int AdjMatrix[7][7];
```

to

```
    int AdjMatrix[8][8];
```

and it won't crash. When you have `queue` in `main`, it *works by coincidence*.

---

By the way, I strongly suggest you to change the design of your data structures and not to use pointers to containers.